# Ramsey Numbers and Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> The Ramsey number $R(G,H)$ of two graphs $G$ and $H$ is the smallest value $n$ such that any 2-coloring of the edges of $K_n$ contains either a red copy of $G$ or a blue copy of $H$ .
>
> The chromatic number $X(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the smallest
>   number $k$ such that $G$ is k-colorable. This means that:
>
> - We use $k$ colors to color the nodes of $G$.
> - Adjacent nodes in $G$ have different colors.
>
> $C(H)$ = the order (that is, number of nodes) of the largest connected component of a graph $H$.
>
> This is a relation between $X(G)$ and $C(H)$ :
>
> $$R(G,H)\ge(X(G)- 1)(C(H) -1) + 1$$

Find $R({P_3,P_3})$, $R({P_3,C_4})$, $R({C_4,C_4})$ . Also, I need to prove that $R({K_{1,3},K_{1,3}})=6$ and  $R({2K_3,K_3})=8$ .

I haven't tried anything yet hence I don't know where to start, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try coloring $K_n$ for small $n$?

Comment: How will that help me to find $R(P_3,P_3)$ and others..?

Comment: @Dream Box : The definition concerns $2$-colorings of the edges of $K_n$, so I guess it's a good place to start.

Comment: I'll admit that remark was rather tongue-in-cheek, but depending on the numbers involved, you may be able to produce all 2-colorings of $K_n$ and keep going up in $n$ until every 2-coloring has a copy of $G$ or of $H$. The combinatorics involved may make this prohibitive, though, I'm not sure at what point.

Comment: I'm not any good at this and that is why I ask for help so I can clarify things and notions for myself

Comment: I guess that for the small graphs $G$ and $H$ it's easier. I have answered a suggestion for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you the idea for $R(P_3, P_3)$. Clearly $n \ge 3$ because your graph $K_n$ must have a subgraph isomorphic to $P_3$ and there is no such subgraph in $K_3$.

What about $n = 4$? Try all the colorings of $K_4$. Is there one that doesn't fit the definition? (I have actually verified that $R(P_3,P_3) = 4$.)

For the other ones, use the identity on $R(G,H)$ to get the smallest $n$ on which you can start checking if $R(G,H) = n$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: When you say try all the colorings of $K_4$ what do you mean? I know that the number of colors that can be used in a $K$ graph is $n$ so what am I missing here?

Comment: To show that a Ramsey number $R(G, H) = n$, you need to show that every $2$-coloring of the edges of $K_n$ contains either a copy of $G$ with all its edges of color $1$ or a copy of $H$ with all its edges of color $2$.

Comment: Well how is $R(P_3,P_3)=4$ when there are at least 4 colors to color $K_4$? $P_3$ is colored in 2 colors, yet there isn't any subgraph in $K_4$ that is colored with the same color twice?

Comment: The coloring is an edge-coloring, not a vertex-coloring.  Also, it need not be (and almost never is) a proper coloring.

Comment: @Dream Box : You only need to find one $n$, because $K_{n+1}$ has $K_n$ as a subgraph, so if $K_n$ satisfies the property, so does $K_{n+1}$. I don't want to do the drawing here, it would take a while... so please do an edge-2-coloring of $K_4$ and see what happens. If you really need it I could try plotting one here.

Comment: so if I do an edge-2-coloring of $K_4$ it would be useful to me with the others as well right? I really need it so I would appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: I can find some time to plot the graph by Sunday.